# Run Functional Test task run cannot be aborted or stopped

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, automated-tests, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines

In TFS 15/ TFS 2015 vNext how can you stop or abort a test run? You can stop the Build that started the test run, but the test run will continue till you shut down the test machines.

Comment: This is a bug in the task. Would suggest you file it through connect.microsoft.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could reproduce your scenario. A test task has started while cancel the build, the test task won't stop. I have already submitted a feedback at website below, you can vote it and monitor the feedback:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3106699

Comment: Im not talking about setting a timeout, im talking about manually stopping or aborting a test run

Comment: Oh, I could reproduce your scenario. A test task has started while cancel the build, the test task won't stop. I have already submitted a feedback at website below, you can vote it and monitor the feedback:   https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3106699

Comment: thanks and voted :) also created github issue https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/2865